# The value of gameplay hours

Tags: pricing

When you buy flooring there is a price per sq foot and it's based on the quality of the material. Some want expensive, some want cheap, some want middle of the road. Can the same idea be applied to video games to apply pricing and if so what tiers would we be looking at? I ask this because we plan on making a dungeon game where we release new dungeons frequently and I'm just thinking how many gameplay hours each dungeon needs for a .99, 1.99, or 2.99 price point?

Is it .99 cents per hour of gameplay that is aimed for?

Comment: This feels primarily opinion based to me. Also, everyone plays at different paces. For example I bought witcher 3 for ~50 and played about 300 hours. So that's about 6 hours per dollar. Is your content six times as good as witcher 3 content? Point being, you can't just say X hours of gameplay is worth Y.

Answer (score 1):

Some players value the price they'll pay for a game the way you just explained: how much does it cost and how long will I play, how much $ per hour?

But that's not the only way you should take to price your game.

How is the competition pricing theirs? How much will it cost *you* to create, publish and market the game? How many copies do you expect to sell? How long will it take you to sell that much copies?

If you think you'll sell 1000 copies at 1$ each week starting at the first week, great! you have a salary of 700$ per week (stores take 30% of what you make). Now if you took only one week to make the game, that's nice, but how long did it take for you to make the game?

You have to think about profitability and having a sustainable business. Unless you have unlimited funds, that is, in which case you're very lucky :)

Comment: You seem to be saying 'it depends on a lot' .. 'like how much you spent, and how much you can afford to sell it for'. This actually has no impact whatsoever on the value of the game. You can spend years making a bad game that has little value on the actual marketplace, and how much the developer can afford to sell something for has no bearing on how much a user would be willing to pay.

Comment: @Gnemlock you're right. My point was more: if you can't make profit by selling the game at a price players are willing to pay, don't bother making that game. Maybe I should update this answer.